# Modx custom tv with multiple inputs

Tags: php, templates, modx

I need to build a custom `tv` in modx that will all a user to select a image, a title and a date.

Can't seem to find any help other than the docs with although detailed don't answer my problem.

Anyone done this before and are able to advise me further

Cheers

Comment: Will you need multiples of this set of data per resource? Otherwise I'd suggest using 3 distinct tvs.

Comment: please clarify "user" you mean an admin user needs to select some data when creating a resource - or do you mean a web visitor needs to select data when they visit the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, if this is what you're trying to archieve, but I think [multiItemsGridTv](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/MIGX) (MIGX) for modX revolution is what you want.

From the docs:

> MIGX (multiItemsGridTv for modx) is a custom-tv-input-type for adding
>   multiple items into one TV-value and a snippet for listing this items
>   on your frontend.
>
> It has a configurable grid and a configurable tabbed
>   editor-window to add and edit items. Each item can have multiple
>   fields.
>
> For each field you can use another tv-input-type.

Essentially, you can make up a set of multiple different template variables (including images), that always belong together. If you then assign your MIGX tv to a template, you can enter as much of these sets as needed per resource.

You can download it via package management or [from the modX Extras Repository](http://modx.com/extras/package/migx).